# Cartesian product with awk to find all possible combinations

Tags: multidimensional-array, awk

I have this function to produce all possible combinations of the string. Starting with capturing the content in the square bracket then use regex to replace it in the string.

I think there is a problem with the loop where I create the nested arrays `pairs` but I'm stuck with it.

```
function delineate(s) {
    tmp=s;
    while (match(tmp, /(\[[^]]*\])/, key)) {
        tmp=substr(tmp, RSTART+RLENGTH);
        value=key[1];
        gsub(/[][]/, "\\\\&", key[1])
        gsub(/[][]/, "", value);
        gsub(/./, "& ", value);
        hash[key[1]]=value;
    }
    solutions=1;
    for (i in hash) {
        n=split(hash[i], a, " ");
        solutions*=entries[++j]=n;
        keys[j]=i;
        for (k=0; k<n; k++) {
            list[i][k]=a[k+1]
        }
    };
# This might be where it causes the error.
    for (i=0; i<solutions; i++) {
        for (j=1; j<=length(entries); j++) {
            pairs[i][j]=keys[j] " " list[keys[j]][i % entries[j]]
        }
    }
    for (i in pairs) {
        tmp=s;
        for (j in pairs[i]) {
            split(pairs[i][j], re, " ");
            gsub(re[1], re[2], tmp);
        };
        res[tmp]
    }
}

BEGIN {delineate("A[BC]T[KM]G"); for (i in res) print i}
```

Let's say for the above input `A[BC]T[KM]G`, the expected output would be:

```
ABTKG
ABTMG
ACTKG
ACTMG
```

This is equal to 2 times 2, so it must have 4 solutions. But I only got this output:

```
ABTKG
ACTMG
```

Comment: With `bash`: `echo A{B,C}T{K,M}G`

Comment: @Cyrus I know how to use `echo` but I would like to use an `gawk` function to reuse it later on. This function is part of a larger program.

Comment: @Tiendu : why not just string square it

Answer (score 3):

Not an `awk` solution but as GNU `parallel` is capable of Cartesian products... To generate all these Cartesian products with GNU `parallel`:

```
$ parallel echo ::: A ::: B C ::: T ::: K M ::: G
A B T K G
A B T M G
A C T K G
A C T M G
```

`A ::: B C ::: T ::: K M ::: G` defines 5 group of inputs for GNU `parallel`, 2 of which contain 2 inputs, the others contain only one. GNU `parallel` calls `echo` with all Cartesian combinations of input groups.

If you want to keep your input format and suppress the spaces in the output you could add a bit of pre- and post-processing with, e.g., GNU `sed`. Example with 9 products and multi-characters singletons:

```
$ u="AA[BCD]TTT[KMN]GGGG"
$ v=$(sed -E ':a;s/\[(( [^] ])*)([^] ])/[\1 \3/g;ta;s/[][]/ ::: /g' <<< "$u")
$ parallel echo ::: $v | sed 's/ //g'
AABTTTKGGGG
AABTTTMGGGG
AABTTTNGGGG
AACTTTKGGGG
AACTTTMGGGG
AACTTTNGGGG
AADTTTKGGGG
AADTTTMGGGG
AADTTTNGGGG
```

Comment: You can avoid the `sed` with: `parallel echo {1}{2}{3}{4}{5} ::: $v` or `parallel echo {=1 '$_=join"",@arg'=} ::: $v`

Answer (score 1):

just string square it ::

```
   echo 'A_T_G BC KM' |
```

> ```
>  mawk 'BEGIN {_ = "." } { __ = $2 
>                               ___ = $3 
>      gsub(_,   "A&T\\&G", __)
>      gsub(_,              __, ___) 
>      gsub((_)_ (_)_ _, "&\n", ___); print ___ }'
> ```

---

```
ABTKG
ACTKG
ABTMG
ACTMG
```

I didn't have  time to fully automate it, but it should give you an idea on how to approach the cartesian product efficiently, without loops (or very very few loop cycles)

so if you change the alphabet to …

```
  A_T_G BCDEFHIJL kmnopqrsuv
```

… the output becomes …

```
ABTkG  AITmG  AEToG  ABTqG  AITrG  AETuG
ACTkG  AJTmG  AFToG  ACTqG  AJTrG  AFTuG
ADTkG  ALTmG  AHToG  ADTqG  ALTrG  AHTuG
AETkG  ABTnG  AIToG  AETqG  ABTsG  AITuG
AFTkG  ACTnG  AJToG  AFTqG  ACTsG  AJTuG
AHTkG  ADTnG  ALToG  AHTqG  ADTsG  ALTuG
AITkG  AETnG  ABTpG  AITqG  AETsG  ABTvG
AJTkG  AFTnG  ACTpG  AJTqG  AFTsG  ACTvG
ALTkG  AHTnG  ADTpG  ALTqG  AHTsG  ADTvG
ABTmG  AITnG  AETpG  ABTrG  AITsG  AETvG
ACTmG  AJTnG  AFTpG  ACTrG  AJTsG  AFTvG
ADTmG  ALTnG  AHTpG  ADTrG  ALTsG  AHTvG
AETmG  ABToG  AITpG  AETrG  ABTuG  AITvG
AFTmG  ACToG  AJTpG  AFTrG  ACTuG  AJTvG
AHTmG  ADToG  ALTpG  AHTrG  ADTuG  ALTvG
```

and doesn't have to be `ASCII-only` either. Change the replacement string to

```
 A&_\360\237\207\272\360\237\207\246_\\&G
```

then you can do cartesian products centered around the Ukrainian flag

```
AB__kG  AI__mG  AE__oG  AB__qG  AI__rG  AE__uG
AC__kG  AJ__mG  AF__oG  AC__qG  AJ__rG  AF__uG
AD__kG  AL__mG  AH__oG  AD__qG  AL__rG  AH__uG
AE__kG  AB__nG  AI__oG  AE__qG  AB__sG  AI__uG
AF__kG  AC__nG  AJ__oG  AF__qG  AC__sG  AJ__uG
AH__kG  AD__nG  AL__oG  AH__qG  AD__sG  AL__uG
AI__kG  AE__nG  AB__pG  AI__qG  AE__sG  AB__vG
AJ__kG  AF__nG  AC__pG  AJ__qG  AF__sG  AC__vG
AL__kG  AH__nG  AD__pG  AL__qG  AH__sG  AD__vG
AB__mG  AI__nG  AE__pG  AB__rG  AI__sG  AE__vG
AC__mG  AJ__nG  AF__pG  AC__rG  AJ__sG  AF__vG
AD__mG  AL__nG  AH__pG  AD__rG  AL__sG  AH__vG
AE__mG  AB__oG  AI__pG  AE__rG  AB__uG  AI__vG
AF__mG  AC__oG  AJ__pG  AF__rG  AC__uG  AJ__vG
AH__mG  AD__oG  AL__pG  AH__rG  AD__uG  AL__vG
```

one can further generalize the cartesian cranker (for the example below, only applicable for non-negative integer powers of 2) - say, to print all non-negative integers up to 8 digits long -

- the non-frills appproach way of sequential iterations took **11.34 secs**,
- but **string squaring** cuts that down by a factor 2.7x and finishes in **4.177 secs**.
- for reference,

  —- `perl 5.36` took **11.78 secs** while
  -- `jot` needed a whopping **17 secs**

> 

```
  ( mawk 'BEGIN { __=10^2^3 * (_ = 1); 
                  for(_ = -_;++_ < __;) print _ }'; )

  out9:  847MiB 0:00:11 [76.5MiB/s] [76.5MiB/s] 
  11.00s user 0.09s system 97% cpu 11.340 total

  a63149791e6364d4c71a3d09f9c8280c  stdin
```

---

```
  ( time ( jot -s '' 10 0 | 

   mawk2 'function ___(__,_,____) { 

      if (!+_) { 
         if (_ != "") { return __ }
         _++ 
      }
      gsub(".", "\\&&", __)
      do { 
          gsub("[&][^&]+", __, __) 
      } while(—_)

       gsub("&0*", "\n",__)
        sub("^\n", "0", __)

      return __ 

   } BEGIN { STDERR = "/dev/stderr" } ($!NF = ___($_, 3))^_' 

  ) | pv ) | xxh128sum

   out9:  847MiB 0:00:03 [ 217MiB/s] [ 217MiB/s]     
   ( jot -s '' 10 0 | mawk2  OFS='\n'; )

   3.57s user 0.46s system 96% cpu 4.177 total

   a63149791e6364d4c71a3d09f9c8280c  stdin
```

---

```
   out9:  847MiB 0:00:11 [73.6MiB/s] [73.6MiB/s] 
  ( perl -le 'for my $__ (0 .. 99999999) {  print  $__ }'; )   

  11.37s user 0.16s system 97% cpu 11.780 total

  a63149791e6364d4c71a3d09f9c8280c  stdin
```

---

```
  ( time ( jot 100000000 0 ) | pvE9 ) | xxh128sum
   out9:  847MiB 0:00:16 [50.3MiB/s] [50.3MiB/s] 
  ( jot 100000000 0; )  

  16.77s user 0.09s system 98% cpu 17.115 total

  a63149791e6364d4c71a3d09f9c8280c  stdin
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was correct about the loop that causes the problem.

```
function delineate(s) {
    tmp=s;
    while (match(tmp, /(\[[^]]*\])/, key)) {
        tmp=substr(tmp, RSTART+RLENGTH);
        value=key[1];
        gsub(/[][]/, "\\\\&", key[1])
        gsub(/[][]/, "", value);
        gsub(/./, "& ", value);
        hash[key[1]]=value;
    }
    solutions=1;
    for (i in hash) {
        n=split(hash[i], a, " ");
        solutions*=entries[++j]=n;
        keys[j]=i;
        for (k=0; k<n; k++) {
            list[i][k]=a[k+1]
        }
    };
    for (i=1; i<=solutions; i++) {
# Add a variable idx here
        idx=i;
        for (j=1; j<=length(entries); j++) {
            divisor=entries[j];
            pairs[i][j]=keys[j] " " list[keys[j]][idx%divisor];
# Update the idx with integer of idx / entries[j]
# By updating the idx, we will be able to generate all possible combinations
            idx=int(idx/divisor);
        }
    }
    for (i in pairs) {
        tmp=s;
        for (j in pairs[i]) {
            split(pairs[i][j], re, " ");
            gsub(re[1], re[2], tmp);
        };
        res[tmp]
    }
}

BEGIN {delineate("A[BC]T[KM]G"); for (i in res) print i}
```

Any idea to improve the code is welcomed :).

Comment: quick note `match(tmp, /(\[[^]]*\])/, key)` - the outermost `(…)` for the `regex` is superfluous grouping :::::::  `match(tmp,  /\[[^]]*\]/,  key)` suffices, or preferably :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::  :::: ::::::: `match(tmp, /[[][^]]*[]]/, key)`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto From the code, you can see that if we remove the parentheses in `match(tmp, /(\[[^]]*\])/, key)`, we can't get the RSTART and RLENGTH variables to use in the next step `tmp=substr(tmp, RSTART+RLENGTH)`. Thanks anyways.

Comment: you already have an array made, so i think `key[0]` contains the substring from `RSTART` to `RSTART+RLENGTH`, pre-cut for you ::::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::: ::::::::::::::::::::::: `echo 'Tue May  2 04:06:15 EDT 2023' | gawk -e '{ match($_, /[0-9]+[:]+[0-9]+[:][0-9]+/, __) }'` ::: then the array `__` contains 3 items :
`0start | "12"`
`0length | "8"`
`0 | "04:06:15"`